Do there exist at least two sets whose union gives the universe in a certain intersection-closed family of sets?
[Crossposted at math.stackexchange.]
Originally I posted a slightly more complicated version of this question. I decided to edit and put it in this simplified form, because I think that if we can answer this question then we can answer the original one too.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of $n$ finite sets. In this case, the family can be regarded as a multiset, since it is allowed to contain multiple instances of the same set. Let $U(\mathcal{F})$ be the universe, i.e. the union of all sets in $\mathcal{F}$.
We require that:

$\mathcal{F}$ is intersection-closed ($\mathcal{F}$ must contain at least one instance of $A \cap B$ for any $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$);
every element in $U(\mathcal{F})$ belongs to at least $\lceil (n-1)/2 \rceil$ sets of $\mathcal{F}$ (every set is counted with its multiplicity).

Is it possible to prove that, for any possible choice of $\mathcal{F}$, there exist $A, B \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $A \cup B = U(\mathcal{F})$?
Maybe a sketch of a possible approach could be starting from the power set $\mathcal{P}(U(\mathcal{F}))$, then try to remove an intersection irreducible set to obtain another intersection-closed family modifying set multiplicites as needed by requirement $2$, and show that we cannot do that without removing all intersection irreducible sets of the same size. Alternatively, start from an intersection-closed family without any $A,B$ such that $A \cup B = U(\mathcal{F})$, then show that if we add sets still without such $A, B$, then condition $2$ keeps being unsatisfied.

Is the terminology 'universe' standard in this context? It seems awkward to me, seeing as you're basically just talking about a union but calling it a universe?

Is the problem solvable/easier without the condition " In this case, the family can be regarded as a multiset, since it is allowed to contain multiple instances of the same set."?

@AlecRhea yes I think so. See for example here.

@FabiusWiesner Note that most of the wikipedia page just refers to sets and unions, which is standard terminology. The phrase universe only shows up in one latter section, and feels idiosyncratic there too imo.

@AlecRhea see also e.g. this paper. Anyway I am not an expert and I am open to whatever alternative terminology to indicate the set of all elements.

@kodlu I am not sure, but I think it is even difficult to find a family satisfying requirement $1$ and $2$ without the multiset stuff. Maybe the only possible families are the power set or the power set minus the universe.

Regardless, it seems everything would get clearer if you replace each set with the complement: Then the assumptions are that the family is union-closed and each element is in at most $\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor $ of the sets in the family, and the desired conclusion is that the family has two members that are disjoint.

Please be aware that every edit of a question or of one of its answers bumps the thread to the front page.
This has happened for this thread already about 20 times in just a few days, and this is a nuisance
for other users. Please refrain from unnecessary edits to your posts.

@StefanKohl sorry, I will try to be less anxious and make less errors next time.

No.
Let $U$ be the Fano plane, a set of $7$ elements. Let $\mathcal F$ consist of the complements of the lines in the Fano plane, each with multiplicity $1000000000000$, together with all their intersections, each with multiplicity $1$. Since each point lies in $4$ of the $7$ line complements, it lies in very slightly more than $4/7$ of the sets, so the second condition is satisfied. But since any two lines intersect at a point, any two line complements must together miss a point, and then the same property holds for any two intersections of line complements.

It's probably easier to see this by thinking complementarily, as your language suggests implicitly and your comment suggests explicitly.

Thank you. I formulated the problem for an intersection-closed family because the question is related to this other question and your answer here can be used to build an example as asked by that question.
